# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Var1' not found in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to find most frequent value per row.
I use for it the following:

```
c<-apply(X = a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){with(as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))), as.character(Var1)[which.max(Freq)])})
```

I get:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Var1' not found
```

This is the input (`a`) I have:

```
 > dput(head(a, 10))
structure(list("e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", NA_character_, "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e"), .Dim = c(10L, 
50L))
```

Comment: What is Var1 supposed to be?

Comment: Your code works when I try it on the sample you've provided. Maybe one of the rows further down has a problem?

Comment: Maybe something in  NA_character_ how can I omit them?

Comment: See 7th row from top